# Managing wheel files with conda

Tags: python, conda, python-wheel

So, I have just started using python and I installed conda to manage the packages, but now I need to install a package (which comes in a "wheel" file, whatever that is?) which is not available from conda repositories and I am not sure what to do. I might be able to use `pip` but I have read somewhere that this is not a good way since I will not be able to use conda features to manage it later. I saw this https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/wheel-files.html article, but it talks about something called "conda recipe" and other thing I have no  clue about and doesn't provide a step-by-step instruction on what to do. So, how do I fully incorporate such "non-conda" packages into conda?

Answer (score -2):

A wheel file is like an .exe file for windows. It installes an application, or in this case a Python package. To install wheel files with conda run the following command in your terminal:

```
conda install -c 'wheel'
```

Replace 'wheel' with your downloaded file. Check out this source for wheel files [Unofficial windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What is `-c conda-forge` do? Doesn't his tell to conda to use conda-forge on-line repository? Should this be replaced with something else if the file is from some other place? Thanks

Comment: I see I made a mistake here, 'conda forge' is a channel from which repositories can be downloaded, like a library. The '-c' option specifies that an additional source of repositories will be used. One would also include this option if installation is from a local file (wheel). Will correct the command.

Comment: This now seems to assume that I have the wheel file downloaded, but I only have a url of the repository and package name. When I go to the url for the package there, are hundreds of versions - how do I know which one I need to download? (And how does the pip or conda know which version of the file to download when you just give the package name?) Thanks

Comment: I also would like to be able to manage this package with things lie `conda update`, so I suspect that there are other things that should be done (e.g. add the url to the list of "channels"?)

Comment: Well if you just have a repository which is not added to your conda environment just run: <conda config --add channels 'new channel'> and there after run <conda install 'package_name'> If you don't specify a version conda will select the latest automatically.

Comment: For some reason this is not working fro me. :(
I can, however, get it installed with the following command `pip install --index-url http://my_pypi --trusted-host my_pypi my_package`. How do I "replicate" this with conda?